# Convert ng-repeater multi-level values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to solve two issues (even if one of them is not really an issue).

I have to iterate trough a two level array of objects, that looks pretty much like this:

```
{"id": "1","details": [{"name": "Name 1","surname": "Surname 1"}]},
{"id": "2","details": [{"name": "Name 2","surname": "Surname 2"}]},
{"id": "3","details": [{"name": "Name 3","surname": "Surname 3"}]},
{"id": "4","details": [{"name": "Name 4","surname": "Surname 4"}]}
```

I also need to convert the printed value, using the ID as parameter:

```
$scope.convert = function (id){
  switch (id) {
    case "1":
       $scope.role = "role 1"
    break;
    case "2":
       $scope.role = "role 2"
    break;
    case "3":
       $scope.role = "role 3"
    break;
    case "4":
       $scope.role = "role 4"
    break;
  }
}
```

Now, in the html, this is what I currently have:

```
<h3>Works - with nested repeaters</h3>
<ul ng-repeat="i in items" ng-click="convert('{{i.id}}')">
   <ul ng-repeat="a in i.details">
      {{a.name}}
   </ul>
</ul>  
<br/>
{{role}}
```

And here are the questions:

- I know that using `ng-repeat` inside another `ng-repeat` does the job, but I think this is not the best way to handle this type of situation. I also tried `ng-repeat-start/end`, but I couldn't figure out how, as I alway got an error saying that end was not found even if it was there.
- If I click on the name to call the convert function, it works, but if I try to call the function into the repeater like this `{{ convert ('{{a.id}}') }}` it fails. All I need, to be fair, is to be able to display, instead of the ID, the converted string directly into the repeater (I cannot change the json file, unfortunately).

Here's what I've described above: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqXBqN?editors=1010

Comment: i think you are reffering to `{{convert(a.id)}}` because using `{{convert('{{a.id}}')}}` will call *convert* with `'{{a.id}}'` as string

Comment: in the function I am actually using the id as a string and not as an int

Comment: BTW, even changing as you said, still get an error

Comment: what are we trying to get here ? *1 - Name 1 - role 1* like output ?

Comment: I need to replace the ID directly, at the end I will only display: role 1 - name 1

Comment: *I need to replace the ID directly* replace with ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108256/discussion-between-kiro112-and-nick).

Comment: Replace with role 1, role 2 .... Basically, when the page is loaded, it should iterate trough the ng-repeat and instead of displaying id: 1, id: 2, id: 3 etc, it should replace all the ids with role 1, role 2 and so on

Comment: or maybe you can just concatenate role and id ? `'role' + id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax Error
`ng-click="convert('{{i.id}}')"` should be converted to `ng-click="convert(i.id)"`

instead of declaring a `role` variable value
add attr to model as the `id` is important

```
$scope.addRole = function (model){
    var id = '' + model.id;
    switch (id) {
        case "1":
            model.role = 'role 1';
            break;
        case "2":
            model.role = 'role 2';
            break;
        case "3":
            model.role = 'role 3';
            break;
        case "4":
            model.role = 'role 4';
            break;
    }
}
```

html

```
<ul ng-repeat="i in items">
    {{addRole(i)}}
    {{i.id}} - {{i.role}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your convert method like as -

```
 $scope.convert = function (id){
     switch (id) {
        case "1":
         return "role 1"
        break;
        case "2":
         return "role 2"
        break;
        case "3":
         return "role 3"
        break;
        case "4":
         return "role 4"
        break;
      }

    }
```

then update your html as-

```
<ul ng-repeat="i in items" ng-click="convert('{{i.id}}')">
      <ul ng-repeat="a in i.details">
        {{i.id}} - {{a.name}}- {{convert(i.id)}}

      </ul>
    </ul>
```

Its output will-

```
1- Name 1 -role 1
2- Name 2 -role 2
3- Name 3 -role 3
4- Name 4 -role 4
```

Comment: That works, thanks. What regarding the other question? Using ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat? any suggestion on how can I improve this as well?

Comment: @Nick i will see it and let you know, if i found any alternative way to do such things. Thanks